# How to load a video as a screensaver on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, video, screensaver

I need to load a video as a screensaver, so that once the screensaver is on, the video starts playing in full screen. On mouse event, the screensaver behavior could be normal, ie, go to the logon screen or quit the screen playing the video. And then on next idle screensaver activation, the video could **continue right from previously left playback** progress.

Basically, a screensaver that can play a video (from settings), and continue that video in a loop on each screensaver session.

Here's an Example video (downloaded): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XG90YYHCSeA

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9):

Found a great light-weight program that allows this, but I haven't tested if videos are continued from previous sessions.

Here's the [sorceforge link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/videosaver/), and here's a direct link to the [VideoScreensaver.zip](http://svn.barnathan.name/opensource/VideoScreensaver/VideoScreensaver.zip) file

**Video Screensaver**

A Windows screensaver that plays videos, with or without sound.

Brought to you by: metasquares

[image: Video Screensaver]

> A basic video player screensaver for Windows, written in C#. Requires .NET 4.5 runtimes. Compatible with most video formats. Hard to find good alternatives out there, so I wrote my own.

Link: http://svn.barnathan.name/opensource/VideoScreensaver/VideoScreensaver.zip

It's Open Source, and only `133 kb` in size!

Comment: Doesn't work on 8.1... When I click apply, it doesn't save. It return to Photo Gallery.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking around. There are lots of basic ones that don't do much other than play a video and let you turn off the sound. Then there is [Lively](https://rocksdanister.github.io/lively/). It is actually focused on live wallpapers and can do a lot more than video, but it can make the wallpaper a screensaver too. The catch is that you can't *just* have a video screensaver. Looks like it has to be a wallpaper at the same time. It is still in development though so I hope it will get the ability to have separate wallpaper and screensaver, including no live wallpaper.

OH, and it does what we are both looking for. It resumes the video where it left off last time! Well, I guess that is just because it is already playing all the time as a wallpaper, but anyway.